# python displaying incorrect value for large ints

Tags: python-3.x

Why is it adding 2 here?  What can I do to fix that?

```
>>> a=4.637421298803135e+16
>>> print("{0:.0f}".format(round(a,0)))
46374212988031352
>>> a=46374212988031350
>>> print("{0:.0f}".format(round(a,0)))
46374212988031352
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Doubles can only store about 15 digits of decimal precision. The first case is obvious. The second case defines the number as an int, but the `f` conversion calls `__float__` to convert before printing since that is what you requested.

Comment: How do I get it to stay a float then, print as a float and without a .xxx or e+16 in the result?